# How to specify extern alias for nuget v3 package dependencies?

Tags: nuget

It was not a problem with nuget v2. All assemblies belonging to the package eventually were added to the assembly references of the project and then you simply could specify extern aliases for any assemblies you'd like.

Now with VS2015 and Nuget v3 when you add a nuget package to a project the only thing you see is the name of the package in the assembly references and there is a corresponding one line in the project.json file. How, in this case, to specify extern aliases for some assemblies belonging to the package when they are not directly referenced in the assembly references of the project?

PS: To avoid questions why it is necessary - because there is a naming collision between the project libraries and the nuget package dependencies. If I change the extern aliases for some of the dependencies the problem is easily resolved without changing names all over the project.

Thank you